# Net Core Web Api moq

Tags: .net, entity-framework, tdd, moq

How to call IRepocitory from Nunit test case.
From postman the debug goes to the linq query , from tdd code the debug does not goes in .
How to configure nunit test case to call EF core for checking API.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]HourlyShareRate value)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        await _shareRepository.InsertAsync(value);

        return Created($"Share/{value.Id}", value);
    }
```

Comment: Please add all your code, such as the NUnit code and Postman request.

Comment: Include what `_shareRepository` is, how it is defined and how it is injected into the controller. Also  show the test you tried where it does not go into the member under test